# Is there a better way to get max(salary) by department and making sure only you get those departments where avg(salary) > 50,000?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Here is the first question asked in the phone interview ?

Employee table has ID, Name, Salary, Department columns. Get me the max salary by department.

My Answer: select max(salary),department from employee group by department.

Follow up Question: 
Now in the above query, I want to get only those departments where average salary is greater than 50,000.

My Answer: I will be using subquery result to filter.

Interviewer: There is simpler way, can you try to do it without subquery ?

Comment: You can use Group By to group the Columns and get the Average per Group and the max per group then use the Where clause to select from the grouped values

Answer (score 2):

You need a HAVING clause:

```
select max(salary), department 
from employee 
group by department
having avg(salary) > 50000
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very similar but u can filter records in groupby using having clause

```
Select dept,avg(salary) as sal from table group by salary having sal > 50000
```